# Eclipse won't start, log error only says: !SESSION !SESSION

Tags: java, eclipse

today when I tryed to start my eclipse (I´m running Eclipse Oxygen in Windows 10, it works perfectly all this past days) and I got the following error message in  `<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.log`:

> SESSION !SESSION !SESSION !SESSION

In order to solve my problem I did all of this not having success:

1 - I deleted the .snap file located in the directory `<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`

2 - I deleted this `<workspace-directory>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.root\[number].tree`

3 - I tryed to start it from the Command Prompt cleaning it first `eclipse.exe --clean`

Does anyone can help here? Thanks in forehand.

Comment: Instead of `--clean` you have to use `-clean`. If `eclipse.exe -data _ws -configuration _config` works then it is a workspace or configuration area issue. Otherwise your installation is broken (which plug-ins did you install?).

Comment: I also used `-clean`, just forgot to write it in the post. I tested with your command but Eclipse shows the blue presentation window for a second and close it again. Yesterday I was working with JBoss Wildfly 10 trying to set up some new configurations but no big deal, it was working perfectly. I shutdown my laptop and since this morning I had this problem.

Comment: Is there a `*.log` file in the new created `_config` directory? Or is there a `_ws\.metadata\.log` file and if yes, what is its content?

Comment: Yes there are many `*.log` files as I tried in many occasions, in `_config` folder. All has the same inside:
**!SESSION**, that´s all.

Comment: There are two types of log files: `_ws\.metadata\.log` and `_config\<timestamp>.log`. Which one do you have?

Comment: The second one in `_config` folder. I specified in the previous comment, because the other path (`_ws\.metadata\.log`) wasn't created.

Comment: I'm also trying to install: `jre-8-windows-x64.exe` again, but it says there's a format error in `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\java.settings.cfg`, inside this file contains this line: `NOSTARTMENU=0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Troubleshooting :

1. Try to start from the command with the clean argument: `eclipse.exe -clean`
2. Try: `eclipse.exe -data _ws -configuration _config`

   - `_config\<timestamp>.log` => Eclipse fails very early, no workspace issue
   - `_ws\.metadata\.log` => also no workspace issue
   - Success => workspace issue
3. Maybe your Java installation is broken => **reinstall Java on your System**
4. Maybe a last installed plugin broke your Eclipse installation => [revert installation from the command line](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Revert_an_Update_or_Installation_with_p2)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error with my **eclipse oxygen** (rpc and rap) installation. In my case it had nothing to do with the workspace or installation, because I used a fresh installation with a new empty workspace.

I figured out that my JDK (**jdk1.8.0_131**) caused the strange error messages. I don't think that the JDK is broken, because *eclipse neon* and all other java applications work fine. But obviously there must be some incompatibility.
I also think that it is not a JDK problem, because when it starts it shows the workspace selection dialog. This means that equinox is starting and the swt bundles are loaded. After selecting the workspace to continue it fails.

My solution was to install the [actual JDK (**jdk1.8.0_144**)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and [use this](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) one.

Finally oxygen works.

Comment: I also had to re-install the actual JDK (1.8.0_144), it seems that it lost some files.
Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It can be also problem with loading WORKSPACE. Try to set:

SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG=true

in this file:

eclipse\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.tips.ide.prefs

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if the JDK used to start Eclipse is removed or damaged in some way. 
Especially if you modify the eclipse.ini file to use a JDK with the -vm option and then you **delete this JDK** at some later point not realizing eclipse is using it!

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue; solved it by editing eclipse.ini config file
change the below to include the right jvm path

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_xxx/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```